# Ensim maintenance mode

Tags: linux, maintenance

Following someone's procedure I ran my RedHat Ensim server through maintenance mode.

```
/usr/local/sbin/set_maintenance  
/usr/local/sbin/set_pre_maintenance  
/usr/local/sbin/set_post_maintenance  
/etc/init.d/epld restart
```

Something went wrong and now some services (crond, epld) don't start on startup.

When trying `exit_post_maintenance` I get:

```
Maintenance State is : 4
```

My question is what is this maintenance mode about? Where can I find documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been 4 years since I've used Ensim, but I do recall often running into problems when doing upgrades. I think the general procedure to fix it is to check

```
/var/log/appliance/ensim_appliance.log
```

And find the site that is having issues. Sometimes it was a site over quota, but sometimes other problems would pop up. Then edit the site:

```
EditVirtDomain -f siteXX
```

Where XX is the site that had problems upgrading originally. After successfully editing the site(s), you should be able to restart and exit out of Maintenance mode on the server.